# output of the javascript snippet? javascript variable declarations

Tags: javascript

My first guess is that the following code has the output of 10 and 100. However, after running the code I get undefined and 100 and I don't understand why the function doesn't see the first declaration of x..

```js
var x = 10;
function f() {
   console.log(x);
   var x = 100;
   console.log(x);
}
f();
```

Comment: The actual function looks like: `function f() { var x; console.log(x); x = 100; console.log(x); }`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It helped me understand it now.